# Is Conditional formatting multiple cells based on the value of a single cell possible?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I would like to create conditional formatting for 4 cells where any cell that has the value "four" in it, it will apply the formatting to the 3 cells immediately below it. Is this possible?
Ideally this would then place "3", "2", and "1" in the 3 cells below.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you want to put values rather than formatting that's only possible with VBA

Comment: Unless someone else has a brilliant idea you're best bet is to set 4 separate conditions. First would be the current cell = 4, then the next condition would be the previous cell = 4, then the next would be 2 prior = 4, etc.